# ClientId not updated when deploying - User injected null

Tags: google-app-engine, google-oauth, google-cloud-endpoints

I am creating a project with App Engine and Cloud EndPoints using OAuth 2.0.

I created and configured all the clientIds (WEB, Android and iOS), but when both I run the server in local or I deploy to App Engine PROD, I always get the following problem:

```
WARNING: getCurrentUser: clientId 292824132082.apps.googleusercontent.com not allowed
```

This clientId `292824132082.apps.googleusercontent.com` is the default one generated automatically when you create the Cloud EndPoints the first time, and it is supposed to be overwritten when you configure you own clientIds and generate the Cloud EndPoint Client Libraries. I can see in my `noteendpoint-v2.api` (My API is called `NoteEndPoint`) that the clientIds inside are update, but I cannot get they are published to local or PROD.

Any clue about what I am doing wrong or I am forgetting?

Comment: Any possibility you're pushing to one version (App Engine version, not API version) and calling another?

Comment: App Engine version, not API version? hum, what do you mean?

Comment: App Engine has the concept of versions just like APIs do with Cloud Endpoints. App Engine versions are managed in the admin console. It's possible you are pushing your application (and APIs) to a version of the app that isn't the default.

Comment: Let me check it in detail, I wanna redo everything from scratch to ensure I am not doing anything wrong, but even with 2 versions of my project, it should not be happening in local at least.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are testing your endpoint in API Explorer you need to add it's ID as one of the accepted ones:

```
 @Api(name = "myApi",
     version = "v1",
     ...
     clientIds = {Constants.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID, yourOtherIds}
```

Where Constants.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID is

```
     public static final String API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID = com.google.api.server.spi.Constant.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID;
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Just curious, how did you figure this out?

Comment: @clocksmith it's here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/annotations, just google for com.google.api.server.spi.Constant.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID...