# Broken Cloud Endpoints auth with clientId 292824132082.apps.googleusercontent.com not allowed

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm working on my cloud endpoints app and my authentication is newly broken since upgrading to 1.8.8.  This error occurs when using the API explorer and my javascript client, both being authenticated with Oauth.

Auth is failing since the user injected into the endpoints is null.  In the logs, I see this:

```
[INFO] WARNING: getCurrentUser: clientId 292824132082.apps.googleusercontent.com not allowed
```

I have the client ids set up in my @Api annotation as follows

```
@Api(name = "myApi",
     version = "v2",
     namespace = @ApiNamespace(
        ownerDomain = "api.ryanharter.com",
        ownerName = "hashnote.ryanharter.com"),
     scopes = {"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"},
     clientIds = {Constants.CLIENT_ID_WEB, Constants.CLIENT_ID_ANDROID,
         Constants.CLIENT_ID_ANDROID_DEBUG, Constants.CLIENT_ID_API_EXPLORER},
     audiences = {Constants.AUDIENCE}
)
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Does the user number 292824132082 match that of your constant CLIENT_ID_WEB?

Comment: Nope.  I don't know what that client Id is. I've seen on SO that its a built in default client id that should be overwritten.

Comment: Take a look at my response in [this other thread][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18523508/clientid-not-updated-when-deploying-user-injected-null